# Soure PDF Code Edited and it is nor Visible

Tags: pdf, text, atom-editor, edit

I just edited the pdf source code with a text editor and after saving it all content was not visible. I change it as it was before but the content still not visible.

Could someone help me?

Comment: It's not possible to help you if you do not provide any example of what you have done. See [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by 'source code' ?

Do you mean you opened a PDF file in a text editor and tried to alter it ? That is pretty much doomed to failure, PDF is a binary format, and various parts of it are referenced by a cross reference table, which points to precise offsets within the file. If you edit the PDF file then you may do any of the following:

1) Convert CR/LF to CR or LF or CR/LF pairs
2) Mangle 8-bit binary data into 'something else' which can include a local code page, depending on the editor you used.
3) Altered the offset of a critical object.

All of the above will cause the PDF file to be broken. Almost all of these changes are invisible, so if you 'change it as it was before' you probably didn't, you just changed the **visible** differences.

If the file is broken, then all you can do is replace it with your backup. You did backup the file before you started editing it, right ?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean.

Comment: Then would there be some way to restore the file?

Comment: You would have to be able to figure out **precisely** what the editor did to your file, which is likely to be impossible. The file has been corrupted, almost certainly beyond recovery. I'm going to assume you didn't make a backup before editing it. You don't say how you are opening the PDF file to see that the content has gone, nor any error messages emitted by that application, this is the sort of information you should provide. You could **try** opening the file with Ghostscript. If it can recover the file you could use the pdfwrite device to create a new repaired version.

Comment: Is says "stream Length incorrect", "Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete". The render output from this file may be incorrect. If there's no way to recover it I can do the document again.

Comment: Sounds like you are using Ghostscript, and it sounds like the file is sufficiently damaged that you can't repair it. You'll need to remake the file.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help.